# How to pass a JavaFx primary stage

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to find a way to access the Stage in my main JavaFx class from another class so I can perform some actions on it but I can't since it is passed as a parameter like so:

```
@Override
public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
```

The `WakiliProject` Class in full:

```
public class WakiliProject extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {

        Group root = new Group();

        StageDraggable.stageDraggable(root, primaryStage);

        root.getChildren().addAll(mainContainer);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 900, 654);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Wakili");

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

How can I catch the above Stage `primaryStage` from another Class and do some actions like I do below after initializing the Stage `public Stage newTryEMail;':

```
public class TryEMailController implements Initializable {

    // Initializes the controller class.
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }

    public Stage newTryEMail;

    public void newTryEMailStage() throws IOException {
        newTryEMail = new Stage();

        newTryEMail.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        newTryEMail.initOwner(AddNewEmailController.newComposeNewEmail);

        Parent newTryEMailRoot = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/wakiliproject/Forms/AddNew/NewEmail/TryEMailController.fxml"));

        StageDraggable.stageDraggable(newTryEMailRoot, newTryEMail);

        Scene newComposeNewEmailScene = new Scene(newTryEMailRoot, 590, 670);

        newTryEMail.setScene(newComposeNewEmailScene);
        newTryEMail.show();
    }
}
```

from another class called `TryEMailController`?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
public void newTryEMailStage(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        newTryEMail = primaryStage;
```

And in the start method:

```
newTryEMailStage(primaryStage);
```

Answer (score 1):

You pass the primaryStage reference from the start() method to the class that you want to have access to it.  Then you store a reference to the primaryStage object in the class that you want to have access to it.  If you are trying to "catch" the reference to the primaryStage object prior to the start() method running, there is no way I know of to do that.  So organize your code accordingly.

Comment: Would you please mind illustrating that. I'm trying to use the `primaryStage` in another Class